# how to change the color of a particular character/word in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a long string as a paragraph and want to color particular word(all number of occurrence in string) within the string. Can any one help me out?
Thanks

Comment: is you string static?

Answer (score 5):

Convert the string to an attributed string (mutable), then search the string to find the ranges of the parts you want to change / highlight and add attributes to those ranges of your attributed string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use
https://github.com/kovpas/BOString

Then your code can be like this:

```
NSString *string = @"String test String";
NSAttributedString *result = [string bos_makeString:^(BOStringMaker *make) {
        make.foregroundColor(UIColor blackColor]);
        make.each.substring(@"String", ^{          
               make.foregroundColor(UIColor greenColor]);
        });
    }];
```

This will make each "String" in your text green. And the rest is black. Then put this attributed string to your UILabel\UITextView etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try This it will work out

Note: We can't show "in one label or textfield different colors".So take labels "equal to the number of letters in a word". side by side to view as one label.

In Viewcontroller.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf5;
```

In ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableString *strName=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"ABCDE"];
    for (int i=0; i<[strName length]; i++) {
        NSString *str=[strName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

        if (i==0) {
            self.tf1.text=str;
            self.tf1.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
        }
        else if (i==1){
            self.tf2.text=str;
            self.tf2.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if (i==2){
            self.tf3.text=str;
            self.tf3.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
        }
        else if (i==3){
            self.tf4.text=str;
            self.tf4.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        }
        else if (i==4){
            self.tf5.text=str;
            self.tf5.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Category to UILabel and Add these functions as it is in it.**

```
  - (void)boldRange:(NSRange)range {
    if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)]) {
    return;
 }
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText;
    if (!self.attributedText) {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text];
} else {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
}

  [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize] } range:range];
  self.attributedText = attributedText;

}

- (void)boldSubstring:(NSString*)substring {
  NSRange range = [self.text rangeOfString:substring];
  // [self boldRange:range];
  if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)]) {
    return;
  }
  NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText;
  if (!self.attributedText) {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text];
  } else {
      attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
  }

  while (range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
      [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize] } range:range];

      NSRange rangeToSearch;
      rangeToSearch.location = range.location + range.length;
      rangeToSearch.length = self.text.length - rangeToSearch.location;
      range = [self.text rangeOfString:substring options:0 range:rangeToSearch];
      [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:    [UIColor redColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize] } range:range];
      self.attributedText = attributedText;
    }

}
```

**Use is as**

```
 [someLabel boldSubstring: @"0"];
```

I have made it to change color and Bold particular characters. Change it accordingly 
Hope It helps.

Answer (score -1):

In the Interface builder you can directly set it to Attributed as shown in the image,

[image]

Here you can select the particular world and change its color.